# Stacking of images when loaded - Slick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

We are using slick slider for a clients project and it has been working perfectly so far, however I have noticed something, I don't know whether it is a bug or something that I am missing something.

When the slick slider is loaded, just before you get the whole slider visible in the viewport it doesnt load properly and stacks at bottom of each other with half of the slider of the page. Then whole slider is visible in the viewport it jumps back to how it should, almost like it has re-slicked its self.

Below is the code for my Slick Slider

```
$('.css_slider').slick({
     infinite: true,
     speed: 500,
     fade: true,
     cssEase: 'linear',
     autoplay: true,
     autoplaySpeed : 8000,
     adaptiveHeight: true,
     dots: true
});
```

and Images looks like as in link [here](http://i67.tinypic.com/2na4mj8.png)

I have read on various places and found this link[Github link for same issue](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/779)

But it is not working for me. I am still getting same ugly effect.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried delaying the function until the dom is loaded?

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    $('.css_slider').slick({
     infinite: true,
     speed: 500,
     fade: true,
     cssEase: 'linear',
     autoplay: true,
     autoplaySpeed : 8000,
     adaptiveHeight: true,
     dots: true
    });
});
```

or, if that doesn't work:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.css_slider').slick({
     infinite: true,
     speed: 500,
     fade: true,
     cssEase: 'linear',
     autoplay: true,
     autoplaySpeed : 8000,
     adaptiveHeight: true,
     dots: true
    });
}, 2000)
```

Comment: Can you throw together a jsfiddle?

Comment: Not Sure.. let me try creating same effect